# Do verses 11, 12, and 176 in surah An-Nisa'a apply to my grandmother and grandfather?

Tags: inheritance

My grand-mother is in ill. So, their children decided to distribute the property which they have. My grand-father and grand-mother have their own property. So, I have searched in net to know about inheritance law in Islam.

In Quran Al-Nisha 11, 12 and 176 are speaking about Inheritance law. I have doubt that whether that law is only applicable after the person(s) died?

My grand-mother and grand-father are alive. Can we use those laws?

Comment: Well first we don't speak about inheritance unless people are dead. Therefore i have a Question: Are your grand-parents only ill or are they sane (or not capable of acting)? because i can't imagine how their kids can distribute their money while they're alive! Only if they are sane one could choose a Wali to handle with their Money and belongings!

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance Law is only applicable when a person dies. A person should write (or get it written) his will, but it will only be applied once he/she dies.

If a person want to distribute any of his belongings before his death, then he is free to do so, but inheritance law does not apply to that. It can be a gift.

Answer (score 1):

Providing a will for after death is not suggested in Islam. The way how the wealth will be divided in case that someone dies is clearly defined in the Quran. As such, someone writing a will which will be effective **only after death** is wrong.

A person can distribute the wealth according exclusively to his will/desire (without being forced to respect any rules for wealth distribution) only when he is alive. And the distribution of the wealth should be done while the person is alive. Otherwise if the person dies and writes a will which gets affective once he/she passes away, that will is not accepted by Islam. In that case the distribution of the wealth should be done according to the Islamic rules.

Long story short. You can distribute your wealth while you are alive. Once you are dead the Islamic Law takes over.

Comment: Unfortunately at this day of age, a will is needed for after death, which is based on Islamic rules. In the majority of the world, if you die without a will the money will mostly go to the spouse. This is why a will is mandatory for all Muslims living under a country with no Islamic inheritance rules.

Answer (score -2):

Islamically,estate of a relative can't be devided as inheritance between heirs unless the relative is dead. If divided during his lifetime (I.e his illness) it is a nullity,.............

Comment: This doesn't seem to be more useful than the already existing answers. Please consider elaborating your answer.